# Concerns about irate for Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, irate

I have irate where it will only show up in simulator with the following code.

```
 [iRate sharedInstance].previewMode = YES;
```

But without it will not show up in simulator, is that normal? Here is the whole code in the view did load.

```
   [iRate sharedInstance].applicationBundleID = @"com.example.example";// Replace this
   [iRate sharedInstance].usesUntilPrompt = 4;
   [iRate sharedInstance].previewMode = YES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the simulator.

The [documentation](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) specifies that the default days and uses until prompt is 10 days. That is probably why it is not showing up for you.

The preview mode you are using always shows the iRate prompt at launch, regardless of what settings you have. This is for testing purposes. If you remove the preview mode, and set your days and uses until launch to 0, it will show up when you launch the first time.